# How to parse and retrieve images with Nutch

Tags: parsing, solr, html-parsing, nutch

After studying many articles and some questions on StackOverflow, I know that I will need to write a customized parser plugin for the purpose and I also know how to do this, but I am stuck at how to proceed.

In fact I am confused with the "flow chart" of the system, which perhaps needs too much in depth study of the Nutch crawling and parsing mechanism. Where to start? Customising the HTML parsing process, then parsing the img tags on the relevant pages and finally completing the process with tools like JSoup etc.

For example let I have to crawl the web and collect all the images of some specific brand item. The images search will take place by the file name and the surrounding text (this makes it necessary to include text parsing as well).

How should the system flow chart look like to start writing the customized plugin for?

I am using Nutch 1.12 and Solr 6.3 integrated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me start by saying that what you're trying to do is not an easy task, but let's go step by step:

1. Assuming that you don't have all the URLs of the images before the crawl begins, you need to crawl the entire web, but you only need to keep the images in your index (and all the associated metadata). For this particular issue you can use the [mimetype-plugin](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/plugin/mimetype-filter) one of the sample configurations does a simplistic version of this (block everything and show only the images).
2. You need to extract metadata about the image (size, colors, etc.) the good news is that Tika already parse the images and detect a lot of metadata. And you'll need to write a custom parse filter for extracting all the additional data that you want.
3. Also you'll need to extract the text around the image, this is not really hard in an `HtmlParseFilter`, the tricky part is how would you *relate* this content with the image metadata. One way you can accomplish this is writing a custom `ScoringPlugin` to share the data from the original HTML page (where the text is) to the actual `NutchDocument` for the image itself (keep in mind that this are processed in different Nutch steps). One other chance is to index this as two separated documents (image metadata + metadata extracted from the HTML), and do a group/join on the query side of your application (web application for instance).

Some additional notes, this particular use case is not really straightforward to implement at the moment with Nutch's out-of-the-box features, but is definitively doable. I built an image search engine based on Nutch and Solr following the previous approach.

Comment: Great. Currently the image properties like face detection, color, size etc are kind of a future work for me, I will do only the rest of the things. Do you have any blog article etc explaining the search engine you built?

Comment: A blog post explaining how everything is glued together is on my roadmap, but at the moment it's not written yet, sorry. I delivered a talk that mentioned some of the work done on the image search engine on last year ApacheCon: you can listen to [the audio](https://feathercast.apache.org/2017/02/10/apachecon-seville-2016-building-a-search-engine-for-the-cuban-web-nicolas-malin-julien-nicolas/) and [slides](http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/apacheconeu-2016.pdf) but not sure how helpful will be.

Comment: //you can accomplish this is writing a custom ScoringPlugin to share the data from the original HTML page (where the text is) to the actual NutchDocument for the image itself//
Could you please elaborate this a little? Where will this take us to?

Comment: This basically is "reversing" the problem, in your parser you'll identify the `img` node and then the text around it, and then you'll whan to share this text around the img node with the specific `Outlink` of the corresponding image. Take a look at https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/java/org/apache/nutch/scoring/ScoringFilter.java#L151-L153

Comment: Keeping in mind that I am not going to extract and use metadata of the images with Tika, Do I need an ImageParser plugin for the rest of the task?